# "Put it at the backseat" or "Put it onto the backseat"?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, prepositions

What preposition should I use in the expression "put ***_*__** the backseat"?

The sentence goes like this:

> I have a few items on my plans, item A is the least important one, so I will put it  ***_*__** the backseat.

Should I use "at" or "onto" here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the idiom you are looking for is *to take a backseat*, which means to be in a position of less importance or a position of not being in control. If you’re in the driver’s seat, you’re in control of the car; if you’re in the back seat, you’re not in control.

Here are some examples of this idiom from the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA):

> “The sandwich was gooey from cheese and crisp from the grill, though the ham **took a backseat** to the other ingredients.”
>   “Search and rescue **had taken a backseat** to all the duties of a sheriff to serve and protect”
>   “Problems of the developing world, which have often **taken a backseat** at G-8 summits, look likely to be pushed to the sidelines yet again”
>   “But questions like these **take a back seat** to more pressing concerns”
>   “Whatever biological imperatives this trip began with, they’re now **taking a back seat** to male pride”

There aren’t any idiomatic uses of `put * the backseat` in the COCA so I don’t think the idiom you thought you were trying to use is one that is in common use.

If you are speaking literally about placing objects or people into the back seat of a vehicle, you can use *in*, *on*, *into*, or *onto*, depending on the circumstance. You can only use *into* and *onto* for motions, while *in* and *on* can be used for either state or motion. Generally, you use *in* and *into* for people, and *on* and *onto* for objects, although sometimes people are *on* a backseat, though typically only if they are not sitting normally. Also, both *back seat* and *backseat* appear to be in equally common use. Examples from COCA:

***In*** examples:

> “He takes the sleeping child and places him **in the backseat** for the woman.”
>   “When riding **in the backseat** with two other people, you may sit on either side but never on the ‘hump.’”
>   “They drove him twenty miles to a hospital, my mother sitting **in the back seat** with the old man’s head in her lap.”

***On*** examples:

> “You can disassemble the tripod and place it **on the backseat** of your car.”
>   “Roy dropped a bag **on the back seat**.”
>    “If he got lucky and made it there with a lot of time to spare, his laptop was **on the back seat**, and he had a ton of paperwork to catch up on.”
>   “I took Alice along to sit **on the back seat** and steady those boxes all the way to Greenville”

***Into*** examples:

> “She climbed **into the back seat** and the car rolled forward and stopped again.”
>   “The woman picked up a woven basket and hopped **into the back seat**.”
>   “He envied the young officer who had pushed the guy **into the back seat** and slammed the door shut before reporting in on the radio”

***Onto*** examples:

> “She tucked the phone more securely into a pocket of her purse, unlocked the door, and slid the cat carrier **onto the backseat**.”
>   “Perhaps the detective imagined her thrown **onto the back seat** after being made unconscious in some manner.”
>   “Then Dad and I hurried out to load my Washington Stars **onto the back seat** of the Studebaker.”
>   “The young thin guy tossed his bag **onto the back seat** and slid right in after it.”
>   “Larry settled Alison **onto the backseat**, climbed in behind the steering wheel, and sat, staring through the windshield. He didn’t speak; Alison was deep in exhausted sleep.”

Comment: wonderful answer +1

Answer (score 9):

Well you could save yourself some trouble by saying you are going to postpone it.

I'm not familiar with this idiom about back seats. There is an idiom "to put on the back burner" which also means to postpone or delay.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper use is neither of those choices, but, rather, either "in the back seat" or "on the back seat".

I'd use "on the back burner" as @delete suggests.

Answer (score 0):

"Put it at the backseat," sounds intuitively odd. But there seems to be a rather poetic use of "put" and "at" when one puts something at the presence or body of another person.  Here is an example from The Acts of the Apostles, Chapter 4 (New International Version, later 20th Century and linguistically updated):

> And God’s grace was so powerfully at work in them all that there were
>   no needy persons among them. For from time to time those who owned
>   land or houses sold them, brought the money from the sales and ***put it
>   at*** the apostles’ feet, and it was distributed to anyone who had need.

Actually, I found this page because I searched "put it at" after writing this.

> If only lies would emit methane from mouths as do beans elsewhere, we
>   could put candles at the lips of both politicians and press.

Answer (score 0):

Should you use "at" or "onto":
There is no fix rule per se, and mostly it's a matter of context, we tend to use one preposition over another. There are many exceptions and overlapping situations.

And if you wish to use a proper idiom, then,as explained,use:

to take a backseat

to put it on the back burner.

Alternatively, use COCA.