# What is the difference between "into" and "onto"?

Tags: prepositions, differences

I see both used, at times, almost interchangeably. What are the general guidelines?

Comment: To me the difference in usage is fairly clear, as a native speaker - but I can definitely accept that there are some subtleties here. Which ones, I would not know however. Perhaps you could give us a few examples where you're unsure? :)

Comment: Related: [Put “At” the Backseat or Put “Onto” the Backseat?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2439/)

Comment: Just put on the backseat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As reported by the NOAD, *into* has the following meanings:

1. expressing movement or action with the result that someone or something becomes enclosed or surrounded by something else. (*Cover the bowl and put it into the fridge.*)
2. expressing movement or action with the result that someone or something makes physical contact with something else. (*He crashed into a parked car.*)
3. indicating a route by which someone or something may arrive at a particular destination. (*The narrow road that led down into the village.*)
4. indicating the direction toward which someone or something is turned when confronting something else. (*with the wind blowing into your face*)
5. indicating an object of attention or interest. (*a clearer insight into what is involved*)
6. expressing a change of state. (*a peaceful protest which turned into a violent confrontation*)
7. expressing the result of an action. (*They forced the club into a humiliating and expensive special general meeting.*)
8. expressing division. (*three into twelve equals four*)
9. informal (of a person) taking a lively and active interest in something. (*He's into surfing.*)

*onto* means:

1. moving to a location on the surface of something. (*They went up onto the ridge.)*
2. moving aboard (a public conveyance) with the intention of traveling in it. (*We got onto the train.*)

As side note, in some cases it is correct to write *onto*, but in some cases it is correct to write *on to*.

> You climbed onto the roof.
>   Let's go on to the next chapter.

Answer (score 4):

kiamlaluno's answer is comprehensive. A simplified answer is

> put A **into** B

means A is somehow inside B and enclosed by it.

> put A **onto** B

means B has a horizontal surface on top of which A now rests.

It's the difference between in and on.

Comment: It's actually just a flag bit in object B ;-P </inform-joke>

Answer (score 1):

You get **into** a cockpit and **onto** a highway. We go **in to** be able to say we were here but we are always the ones who move **on to** the next one.

Inside the cockpit, on top of the highway. We go in(side) (in order) to be able to say we did it; when you are ready to move on to something better let me know; I'll get you onto the waiting list.